# drupal form_validate don't get called in every case

Tags: forms, validation, drupal

I have a drupal 7 installation. 
I wrote a form_validate function for an entityform.
So far it works fine. 
In this form is an image-field. After uploading an image and then submitting the form the form_validation function is no longer called!
Why this?

Comment: Please post your code up here so we can see what could be causing the problem.

Comment: I found the problem: when upload an image in your form, a new form gets created!!!
while debugging the form-id's I found this.
Assume your form is called form-a, then a new form with the name form-a--2 is created.I solved it by attaching the same form_validation to the new form. And it works. Somehow strange, isn't it?

Comment: Drupal forms ids always change after ajax requests, but only the html ID, not the ID Druapl refers to the form to load or render it. The validation shouldn't need to be attached to both so not sure what is happening there. [This post on drupal.org](https://drupal.org/node/1604850) discusses the topic.